# method within a JS class coming with up with not a function

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a hidden form, due to two forms on the same page doing different submissions. The hidden form is then holding the password field that once entered it will show a section to the user, this part is all working with PHP and when the button is clicked. However, I have a `addEventListener` on the input field to listen out for when the user presses 'Enter'. Within the Event Listener I have declared the name of the button and then `click()` method to submit the form. But I run into the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.confirmPassowrd() is not a function?
```

**JS**

```js
enterKey()
{
    document.querySelector('#password-confirm').addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
       if (e.key === 'Enter') {
           this.confirmPassword();
       }
    });
}

confirmPassword()
{
    document.getElementById('confirm-password').click();
}
```

I'm not entirely sure what is happening, but if I put this as a normal function on the page where the html is, and call it it withing the enterKey() method it works fine. Any suggestions?

Kind regards,

James

Comment: How was this a duplication?

Comment: I added a duplicate question with the class for `this`.

Answer (score 1):

You are losing the context of your class in the `keydown` event listener callback.

Try switching the `function (e)` you are passing in to an arrow function instead: `e =>`

An arrow function will preserve the lexical `this` of where it is created, whereas a `function` will take whatever `this` is handed to it when it is invoked. Therefore within your event listener function `this` no longer means "the instance of the class I am defined in".

Comment: thanks very much for this explanation, changing the function to an arrow function now works as expected. i will need to dig deeper in to the keyword this, I understand that it is used differently where ever it is used.